# VsFlex7 (vb6) on Windows 10

Tags: vb6, controls, windows-10, vsflexgrid

I'm trying to edit some old source code from another developer on my windows 10 machine.  This particular project requires the use of the VsFlex7 control (vsflex7L.ocx and vsflex7L.oca) which needs to be registered in Windows before I can use the control in vb6.

When I try to use it in vb6 I get the following error...
[image]

So then I check the vb6 project file source and see this which shows the control I had issues with in the first place (VSFlexGrid) has a CLSID of `Object={C0A63B80-4B21-11D3-BD95-D426EF2C7949}#1.0#0; vsflex7l.ocx`...
[image]

I also checked the form source as well to see the same thing...
[image]

So then I dig in the registry and find this...
[image]

So then I try to run command prompt (as admin) and do the following...

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 Vsflex7L.oca /u
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 Vsflex7L.oca
```

The problem is, when I try to do `C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 Vsflex7L.oca /u` regsvr32 runs about a million times at the speed of light and bogs down my PC to the point where I have to press the power button to reboot the PC.  After running the command to try and unregister the oca my machine is useless.  I can't even bother to kill tasks in task manager because so many copies are being ran at once, over and over again!!

Any ideas what I can do to get this control registered so I can fix this little tiny bug in the source I have?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to comments to my original question, I have now noticed that I should more than likely be trying to track down CLSID `2C4CDB4E-6162-11D3-BD96-B76E8682527F` in the registry.  However, this one I can not find...  Should I just add it?  If so what dll or ocx should it point to?

Comment: Can you try that again on another machine?

Comment: Shouldn't the extension be .ocx instead of .oca?

Comment: ocx files are registered, oca files are not - they are created automatically by VB. Why are you highlighting that registry entry? The clsid does not match the error message. The clsid in the error message appears, from a google search, to be associated with "VSPPG7 VideoSoft Property Pages". Open your vbp file and check that clsid for what program it is associated with, then try registering that ocx/dll.

Comment: Ahh what a goof!  I grabbed the wrong SS...  Give me a sec and let me update the question, sorry guys!

Comment: Thanks for the help @MarkL in pointing to the correct CLSID!  :)  I have now updated my question with a little more detail as well as an update at the bottom.

Comment: @BillHileman I always register the `ocx` files (for controls) in vb6 but this time I just noticed the registry had that `oca` file referenced.  Both exist in the SysWow64 directory and I'm guessing the OCA file is some type of support file for the OCX.

Comment: I've encountered similar situations and in my situations, I seem to recall deleting the .oca file and letting the system re-create it, but because I cannot be 100% certain that it would solve your problem or be automatically recreated, I suggest that you might try renaming the file (oca) instead.

Comment: An oca file contains type library information and is also a cache for it for the related control. There was a MS kb article which doesn't appear to be available any longer, but the Wayback Machine has a copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20150112014532/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK thanks to all the comments in my question I ended up being lead to the correct solution!  So that you to all that contributed, specifically MarkL!

Tracking down the two following dlls was the first step, it's important to note you need the correct version!  I ended up downloading a Chinese version at first and it was showing all my controls in a different language.  I ended up finding out these were needed from some research on the web on that CLSID that was pointed out to me.  In this case it was all related to the VSFlexGrid control by VideoSoft.

- Vsppg7.dll
- vsStr7.ocx

I then went to the virustotal website and uploaded both to do my checking just to make sure they were spiffy clean and did not contain any viruses.

Next I ended up tossing them into my `C:\Windows\SysWow64` folder (because they are all OLD x86 related files).

Finally I ended up running the four commands...

- C:\Windows\SysWOW64>`regsvr32 Vsppg7.dll /u`
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64>`regsvr32 Vsppg7.dll`
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64>`regsvr32 vsStr7.ocx /u`
- C:\Windows\SysWOW64>`regsvr32 vsStr7.ocx`

Once I did that, I opened up VB6 and the project in question, then clicked the control and tried to click the `FormatString` property.  This time instead of the error I was greeted with a nice GUI that allowed me to change things!

Hope this helps someone else even though all this is ancient!

Comment: If available, digging up and reinstalling the VSflexgrid s/w would have resolved this, I expect. Since it appears that the missing file(s) are a sub-component of the control you do include and reference, it should have been installed with the original relevant package installation.

Comment: First thing I tried...  That old xp installer just will not work at all on Windows 10.  The company no longer supports any of that etc..

Comment: Just to summarize... it sounds like a dependency of the control you were using was not registered, is that correct?

Comment: @DaveInCaz, yea.  In a nutshell it was due to the following...  Old installer that I could not use on a new OS (not supported).  When trying to manually install the control it had other depended controls that needed to be loaded as well.  It just took some more research and someone to point out to me that the CLSID in the message box was that of a sub control and not the primary control I thought it was.  ;)

Comment: If the control (OCX) happened to come with a .DEP file that might also list out its dependencies.

Comment: @DaveInCaz will that include the dependencies of the dependencies?

Comment: No, these would be in the .DEP files of the first dependencies.

Comment: That's what I was thinking...  And I don't have all those.  But thanks for the input.  ;)